# I am getting this error "There is no row at position 0." vb.net as the frontend and sql server 2008 as the db

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, t-sql

This is my code, I m getting error "**There is no row at position 0.**"

Sub loadservicetype()

```
    Dim str As String = "SELECT servicename FROM tbl_activity WHERE activity= '" & CmbActivity.Text & "' "
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sdr As New SqlDataAdapter(str, connection)
    sdr.Fill(dt)

    TxtServiceType.Text = dt.Rows(0)("servicename").ToString


End Sub
```

Comment: please use parametrised queries. This is open to **SQLi**!!! In terms of the question, are you sure your query is returning a result?

Comment: The error is clear enough. Did you tried your query in a sql environnement? And to avoid this case later, you should check if there is any result in dt, to avoid error message...

Comment: Is there any other way to load data from db to a txtbox when the selectionindex of a combobox changes.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is Always Use `SQL Parameter` to AVOID **SQL injection**
Like this

```
 Dim commandText As String = "SELECT servicename FROM tbl_activity WHERE activity=@ID"
     Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)


        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID


        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim rowsAffected As String = command.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Catch ex As Exception
            throw
        End Try 
    End Using
```

[MSDN SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your `DataTable` is Doesn't Return any rows which You Are Trying to Access

```
If dt IsNot Nothing Then 

 If dt.Row.Count>0 Then
 TxtServiceType.Text = dt.Rows(0)("servicename").ToString
 End If

End If
```

Comment: You also appear to be making an assumption that the search term is an integer - I would prefer to use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cmdactivity.Text)` instead.

Comment: Just backing up @Psychemaster: especially as the OP's original concatenation surrounds the activity value in quotes: `WHERE activity= '" & CmbActivity.Text & "' "`.

Comment: Actually, you'd be better using something like `If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then` to check for rows. Because of the `Dim dt As New DataTable` declaration in OP's original code, dt will never be nothing, even if it's empty.

Comment: Now Updated...@Psychemaster Instead of `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cmdactivity.Text)` if will prefer `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value=ID`